# Tracking code doesn't put traffic in correct channel

Tags: email, google-analytics

I have a problem with the tracking code for my email campaigns (`?utm_source=email-template...`).

Most of the traffic comes under 'Direct' in Google Analytics and just a tiny bit of the traffic comes under 'Email' in my analytics channel. Sometimes the same link shows in both the 'Direct' and 'Email' channel.

The full source = `?utm_source=email-template&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=enews`

Can you please tell me how to make sure all email traffic is represented in the 'Email' channel?

Comment: have tried using the builder? https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

Comment: Yep, that's how I got the code in the first place..

Comment: Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your channel grouping settings have email set as a "System Defined Channel" and create an additional rule that defines source as `source matches regex ^(email|email\-template)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that utm parameters are retained on page URL and not lost as a result of page load or redirect and also sub-domain and cross-domain tracking (if required) is setup correctly to retain original traffic source.

hope this help